# Upload pics to iCloud from old iPhone not primary iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud

I purchased an iPhone 5S and it was turned on at time of purchase.  However, I did not completely back up all photos to iCloud from old iPhone 4.  I cannot get the iPhone 4 photos to upload to iCloud in order to put them on new laptop.   Help

Answer (score 1):

Transfer them directly to the laptop, using [iPhoto](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/iphoto/id408981381?mt=12) [Mac] or [Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-live/essentials) [Win]